# Why am I getting a 404 with ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, configuration

I'm just starting out with ASP.NET, all my prior experience has been with desktop programming.  VS2010 SP1 and I'm looking at Microsoft's tutorial for a music store.  I'm at the point of trying to make a hello, world page--but it's just returning a 404.

Win 7 64-bit, IIS is installed and working for HTML, I have a static page I wrote that is served up correctly but now I want the server to do something useful.

When I hit the F5 in VS the ASP.NET development server shows up in the taskbar like it's supposed to but all I get is a 404.  Note that this is *NOT* the 404 from IIS, it looks very different.  That says to me that I'm connecting to the ASP.NET server and not the IIS server.

I'm pretty sure it's a configuration issue somehow (there's so little else that I have a hard time picturing there being any other error) but Google isn't turning up anything relevant.  Where should I be looking?

Re: The comments--it's reaching the server as I get back a 404 page, not a server can't be found error.

The tutorial:
http://mvcmusicstore.codeplex.com/releases/view/59112#DownloadId=197609

Comment: The web development server uses high number ports, do you know if you have a firewall that would block access to the ports?

Comment: whats the URL that shows you the 404?

Comment: @K Ivanov: http://localhost:5547/ (With the appropriate slashes which are getting stripped here.)

Comment: Might be a silly question, but did you set the page you're trying to view as the startup page in VS.NET? You should just be able to right click on the page and say "Set as Startup Page".

Comment: @rsbarro:  I'm not seeing that option.  I've tried entering every URL that I can think of that might refer to my tiny bit of code and it makes no difference.  The tutorial didn't show doing anything like that anyway.

Comment: What's the page you're trying to load? Mypage.aspx or something like that?

Comment: @rsbarro:  It comes up simply trying to load the default page which fails, I've tried tacking on everything I can think of to that base and it makes no difference.  Is there even a log file somewhere that tells me what's going on?

Comment: What is the default page called though? Default.htm, default.aspx, index.html, etc? Sorry for all the questions, just asking because I've never seen the default (VS.NET) web server behave like that before.

Comment: I don't think the default ASP.NET server writes logs like IIS does.  You could try checking the Event Viewer to see if there's anything in there. Some other questions that may or may not matter: Is this and ASP.NET application or ASP.NET MVC? Is it a web application or a web site (a web site will show a local path or a url as the project name in the Solution Explorer, a web application will have the project name)? What OS are you using? Can you edit the question and post a link to the tutorial you are using?

Comment: @rsbarro:  It's ASP.NET MVC.  Of course it's local so far.  The OS is Win 7 64-bit.

Comment: I downloaded the MvcMusicStore tutorial and have followed it through to adding the HomeController, which worked fine for me. Is the HomeController what is failing for you? If so, did you create that class in the Controllers folder?

Comment: I didn't call it HomeController but it's in the Controllers folder.  Hmmm.....  That's the one thing I didn't try.  Apparently it has to be named HomeController!

Comment: Cool, so you have it working? Yea, it has to be HomeController to show up at 'localhost:12345', and it will also show up at 'localhost:12345/Home'. If your controller is named Default1Controller then it will be viewable at 'localhost:12345/Default1'. Do you mind if I post that as an answer?

Comment: @rsbarro: But when I tried to access my controller with the name of the controller on the URL (both with and without the "Controller" part) it didn't load.  Now that it's running I'll probably figure out what's up in time.  I'll accept your answer as is, it's close enough.

Comment: @Loren I posted an answer. I tried to address the issue you raised in your last comment, see the Default1Controller in the answer.

Comment: Do you have a default.aspx page?

Comment: @Earlz That's a good point. If there is a default.aspx page it will be displayed instead of the HomeController at localhost:12345. You should still be able to see the HomeController at localhost:12345/Home, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the default page to display, you'll want to create a controller in the Controllers folder called HomeController.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Home/

    public string Index()
    {
        return "Hello From Home";            
    }
}
```

In MVC, the Urls by default are wired to the controller name (minus "controller") and the method name. Creating an Index method is basically the equivalent of creating an index.htm page. Once this controller is created, you should be able to bring up the following urls (assuming that the ASP.NET web server is running on port 12345):

```
http://localhost:12345/
http://localhost:12345/Home
```

Both should display the text "Hello From Home". Also, assume you create a controller like the one below:

```
public class Default1Controller : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Default1/

    public string Index()
    {
        return "This is the index";
    }

    public string MyNewPage()
    {
        return "This is the new page";
    }
}
```

This controller will display at the following Urls:

```
http://localhost:12345/default1 - should show "This is the index"
http://localhost:12345/default1/mynewpage - should show "This is the new page"
```

Comment: Incidentally, I found what really threw me--while I was trying everything I could think of to get the page to come up I made a typo on the one that would have worked.  I only caught it when I went back after your comments and I found the misspelled URL in my browser history.

Comment: Ugh, the typo. Happens to everyone from time to time. Glad you were able to figure out the problem, though.